# rollback in Managed bean doesn't not ignore form validation

Tags: java, oracle-adf

Dear Fellow ADF Expert,

I am using the below managed bean code to insert a new row into a detail table of a master detail relation-ship. "insertNewReturnReason" is used whenever the user clicks a row in a table as SelectionListener event handler. It is supposed to kind of play the role of createInsert binding operation except it tries to rollback the row created before, and then insert a new row under the new id of the master iterator ("AstAssetVOIter"). The other event listener I have is "saveAssetReturn" which is supposed to commit the changes.

The issue I have is with "insertNewReturnReason" which does a rollback first and then inserts new rows in the details table. For some reason the form keeps alerting a field is required which is a foreign key in another table.

The same code was exactly working fine in another project and I didn't have any issue with it and the only things I changed is the name of the iterators and the view object.

I have set the immediate property of the button to true too.

Please let me know if anything comes to your mind.

Thank you,

```
package com.asrandisheh.mis.asset.viewcontroller;


import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import oracle.adf.model.BindingContext;

import oracle.adf.model.binding.DCIteratorBinding;

import oracle.jbo.Row;

//import util.JSFUtils;
import com.asrandisheh.mis.asset.viewcontroller.JSFUtils;

import org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.event.SelectionEvent;
import oracle.binding.BindingContainer;
import oracle.jbo.ViewObject;




import oracle.binding.OperationBinding;

import oracle.jbo.Key;

public class AssetReturn {
    public AssetReturn() {
        super();
    }

    public void insertNewReturnReason(SelectionEvent selectionEvent) {
        //
        System.out.println("Method Call: insertNewReturnReason");

        // maintain the makecurrent behavior
        JSFUtils.resolveMethodExpression("#{bindings.AstAssetsVO1.collectionModel.makeCurrent}", null, 
                                           new Class[]{SelectionEvent.class}, new Object[]{selectionEvent});        


        // Set the binding context
        BindingContext bctx = BindingContext.getCurrent(); 
        BindingContainer bindings = bctx.getCurrentBindingsEntry();


        // get the current row for AST_ASSET table
        DCIteratorBinding astAssetsVOIterator = (DCIteratorBinding) bindings.get("AstAssetsVOIterator");

        Key parentKey = astAssetsVOIterator.getCurrentRow().getKey();

        //You can add your operation code here, i have used simple Cancel operation with Rollback and Execute


        OperationBinding ob= bindings.getOperationBinding("Rollback");
        ob.execute();
//        OperationBinding ob1= bindings.getOperationBinding("Execute");
//        ob1.execute();

        //Set again row key as current row
        astAssetsVOIterator.setCurrentRowWithKey(parentKey.toStringFormat(true));


        Row assetRow = astAssetsVOIterator.getCurrentRow();        

        // print out the current ID
        System.out.println(assetRow.getAttribute("Id"));

        // get the AstAssetReturnsVOIterator and create a new row with default values
        DCIteratorBinding astAssetReturnsVOIterator = (DCIteratorBinding) bindings.get("AstAssetReturnsVOIterator");
        ViewObject assetReturnVO = astAssetReturnsVOIterator.getViewObject();
        assetReturnVO.executeEmptyRowSet();

        // pre-set values for ast_asset_return 
        Row assetReturnRow = assetReturnVO.createRow();
        assetReturnRow.setAttribute("AsetId", assetRow.getAttribute("Id"));
        assetReturnRow.setAttribute("AsrtDate", "1395/12/31");
        assetReturnRow.setAttribute("Stat", 1);

        // switch the status to "RETURNED"
//        assetRow.setAttribute("Status", "RETURNED");


        assetReturnVO.insertRow( assetReturnRow );
    }

    public void saveAssetReturn(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        // Set the binding context
        BindingContext bctx = BindingContext.getCurrent(); 
        BindingContainer bindings = bctx.getCurrentBindingsEntry();


        // get the current row for AST_ASSET table
        DCIteratorBinding astAssetsVOIterator = (DCIteratorBinding) bindings.get("AstAssetsVOIterator");        
        astAssetsVOIterator.getCurrentRow().setAttribute("Status", "Returned");

        OperationBinding ob = bindings.getOperationBinding("Commit");
        ob.execute();
    }
//
//    public void saveAssetReturn(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
//        // Add event code here...
//    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/06-cancelform-java-169125.pdf is probably a good answer.

Comment: Try immediate true on the button.